# cant release Hello World app on android emulator xamarin

Tags: c#, android, android-emulator

i recently installed Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 and xamarin, i downloaded android sdk packages (19,21,23 api). I builted succesfully my solution but on release state i get the following:

```
 `I:Unknown]:              Found Android SDK. API levels: 19, 21, 23
[I:Unknown]:              Found Xamarin.Android 6.1.0
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERSIONS" -e "packages" "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime,Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_21,App1.App1" "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.PackageVersions"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 cat /data/system/packages.xml
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 cat /dbdata/system/packages.xml
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 pm uninstall "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 pm uninstall "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 rm "/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk"
[W:Failed to delete package file: {0}]: One or more errors occurred.
[E:]:                     Deployment failed
Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: Read-only file system
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError(CancellationToken token)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.EndPush(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
```

Please Help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the emulator directly from the Android Virtual Device Manager and let it fully boot?
I've been encountering similar errors and I think it was due to the new emulated device not being ready.

After the device had finished booting to the OS I was able to deploy and run my app (albeit very slowly).

I hadn't banked on it running like a dog despite using HAXM (and I do have a pretty high-spec PC). I'm now considering upgrading from Windows 10 Home to Pro and using Hyper-V.

Comment: Seems to be running fine now - I may not have had the use Host GPU flag set when I created the AVD.